# jackson/json using List<String[]> and data binding

Tags: json, dynamic, data-binding, jackson

I have been using Jackson (which works great BTW) for all the json "tree" that I am traversing until I get to the deepest json level where unfortunately the json properties are "dynamic" such as the below so it does not make sense to create objects for those...

```
 "values": [
{
"duration": 0.20669677067008357
},
{
"weight": 0.013746673955838557
}
]
```

The issue is that "duration" and "weight" are dynamic so I was hoping to use `List<String[]>` for 'values' but I don't think that it is possible.  For example, the next call could have "duration", "weight", and "marketValue" or 10 other properties.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a solution for those interested:

This article/how to was very helpful in understanding the jackson data-binding flexibility:

http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-Annotations-Dynamic-Beans.jsp

Particularly, I chose to use the annotation `@JsonAnySetter` such as this on my POJO:

> private String name;
>       private Object value;

```
@JsonAnySetter
public void set(String name, Object value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
}
```

I then opted to place those name/value pairs into a `Map<String, Object>` for easy retrieval...  Works great!